# Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Parameter 'appPackage' is required for launching application

Tags: android, ubuntu, appium

I'm running latest version of appium (1.0.0-beta.1), on ubuntu (13.10). When I try to run the test connecting to android emulator, I'm getting the following error.

> Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Parameter
>   'appPackage' is required for launching application info: Error:
>   Parameter 'appPackage' is required for launching application
>
> info: Responding to client with error:
>   {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created.
>   (Original error: Parameter 'appPackage' is required for launching
>   application)","origValue":"Parameter 'appPackage' is required for
>   launching application"},"sessionId":null}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match your capabilities as per the following list and use appium 1.0:

```
File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "\\lib");
File app = new File(appDir, "Demo1.apk"); 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","BX903HNX10");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.3");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.demo1");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",".RootActivity");  
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a remote webdriver using a code similar to following code (which is in python)

```
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)`
```

The second parameter desired_caps should pass "app-package" and "app-activity" values

```
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['app-package'] = 'com.example.android.calculator`
desired_caps['app-activity'] = '.ApiDemos'
```

The code snippet in python looks like

```
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['device'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['browserName'] = ''
desired_caps['version'] = '4.3'
desired_caps['app'] = PATH('<path to the apk>')
desired_caps['app-package'] = 'com.example.android.calculator'
desired_caps['app-activity'] = '.ApiDemos'

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```